# Does the dual space of $W^{1,2}(B)$ contain $L^1(B)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $B\subset R^m$, $m\geq 2$, be a unit ball, and $W^{1,2}(B )$ be the Sobolev space. My quesion is whther $(W^{1,2}(B))^*\supset L^1(B)$ holds or not?

Comment: Do you know the answer if $m=1$? (I'm thinking of Sobolev embeddings.)

Comment: I would start with the following (maybe counter) example $$l(\phi)=\int_B\phi(x)\frac{dx}x,$$ $m=2$ and check whether this is a bounded-linear functional or not on $W^1_2(B)$.

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to $W^{1,2} \hookrightarrow L^\infty$ which fails for $m$ large enough, IIRC even for all $m \geq 2$.